# In Python code, after fetching the value via select in the for loop i have to take the index[0]th value

Tags: python, oracle

'Code which i have written'
'''

```
row =  crsr.execute(select hostname, employee_add1, employee_add2 from table)
records = crsr.fetchmany(size)
with open(r"samplefile.txt", "w") as f:
   for row in records:
     print (str(row))
```

'''
'from this select statement i want to get the value of hostname and append this value to the filename.txt. Filename should be something like this'

```
'''samplefile-datetime-hostname'''
```

'How to sort this out?'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
crsr.execute("select hostname, employee_add1, employee_add2 from dual")
records = crsr.fetchmany(size)
for h,a1,a2 in records:
     print(h+"-samplefile.txt")
```

It wasn't clear whether you wanted to open one file total, or one file per table row, but you can easily add an `open()` outside or inside the loop.

You can also import `datetime` and get a date to concatenate into the string.

You may want to strip leading and trailing whitespace from the hostname column value.

Comment: From the executed fetch results i am doing two operations one is adding hostname & UTC datetime to the filename & for each row i will validating using the regular expression to seperate the key value with an binary seperator.

Comment: If you have difficulty, update your question's text with the current state of the code and refine the question.